# EJS ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm trying to pass data from an Express route to EJS but I keep on getting a ReferenceError. This should be a page that renders a table of employees' email addresses and their roles:

```js
<%- include("./partials/header"); -%>
<body class="bg-slate-900 mx-4">
    <%- include("./partials/navigation"); -%>
    <div class="text-white">
        <table class="text-white">
            <thead>
                View Employees
            </thead>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Role
            </th>
            <% employees.map((employee) => { %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=employee.email%></td>
                    <td><%=employee.role%></td>
                </tr>
            <% }) %>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the Express routing code:

```js
app.get('/view_employees', (req, res) => {
    const employees = [
        {email: 'abrown@pd.com', role: 'Administrator'},
        {email: 'jhoffman@pd.com', role: 'HR Representative'},
        {email: 'tcooper@pd.com', role: 'HR Representative'},
        {email: 'vsanders@pd.com', role: 'Employee'},
        {email: 'crollins@pd.com', role: 'Employee'},
        {email: 'pjackson@pd.com', role: 'Employee'},
        {email: 'xwoods@pd.com', role: 'Employee'},
    ];

    res.render('/view_employees', {employees: employees});
});
```

This is the full error. Tl;dr employees is not defined in the EJS:

```
ReferenceError: A:\Node\workplace_incident_reporter\src\views\view_employees.ejs:15
    13|                 Role

    14|             </th>

 >> 15|             <% employees.map((employee) => { %>

    16|                 <tr>

    17|                     <td><%=employee.email%></td>

    18|                     <td><%=employee.role%></td>


employees is not defined
    at eval ("A:\\Node\\workplace_incident_reporter\\src\\views\\view_employees.ejs":16:8)
    at view_employees (A:\Node\workplace_incident_reporter\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
    at tryHandleCache (A:\Node\workplace_incident_reporter\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:36)
    at exports.renderFile [as engine] (A:\Node\workplace_incident_reporter\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (A:\Node\workplace_incident_reporter\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (A:\Node\workplace_incident_reporter\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (A:\Node\workplace_incident_reporter\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (A:\Node\workplace_incident_reporter\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at A:\Node\workplace_incident_reporter\app.js:18:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (A:\Node\workplace_incident_reporter\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: "a ReferenceError" - _which_ error?

Comment: @CherryDT my bad I forgot that. I just updated the question to include the error.

Comment: your HTML table nesting is incorrect. your <thead> tag should contain your header row <tr><th>header 1</th><th>header 2</th>...</tr> and then your data rows should go in a <tbody> tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is another case of making sure you test your app with `nodemon app.js` instead of `node app.js`.